# Form Helper argument is nil value why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Regardless of what I have tried to put in as the argument to the form helper I get a nil value. I'm trying to user form helpers in my code but I'm finding it easier to make it work with regular forms. I know the form helpers are the best practice so I want to learn what it is that I'm doing wrong or if this is a case where I shouldn't be using form_for

I checked the console that rails give us in the browser and `@user`, `@session`, `@users`, `@sessions` are all `nil`. I don't know what else I can pass in.

Why won't this work:

```
<%= form_for(@session) do |f| %>
  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
   <div class="actions form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Sign In", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
   </div>
```

But this will:

```
<form  action="<%= session_path %>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>"/>
  <input type="email" name="user[email]" placeholder="your email"/>
  <input type="password_digest" name="user[password]" placeholder="password">
  <input type="submit" name="name" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

Some insight on my follies would be great. Thanks!

Sorry for the edit Here is the `session_controller`'s `create` method in case it helps:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: user_params[:email])

    if user && user.authenticate(user_params[:password])
      session[:current_user_id] = user.id
      flash[:message] = "Thanks for loggin in " + user.first_name
    else
      flash[:message] = "Username or Password combo are not correct"
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Comment: also I thought maybe declaring `@session = session[:current_user_id] = user.id` might resolve the problem but no cigar.

Comment: The form belongs to which view file?

Comment: application/welcome.html.erb

Comment: Please post your `welcome` action. That's where you need to define `@session`.

Comment: you can try this `<%= form_for(:session, url: session_path) do |f| %>`

Comment: @pardeep-saini that worked however it didn't send the params with the submit. I don't know why. @mmichael my welcome action has `@session = session[current_user]` and current_user has  `@current_user ||= session[:current_user_id] &&
  User.find(session[:current_user_id])` I'll investigate more in the morning. Thanks for the help tonight gentlemen.